# Replace current navigation controller with another navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I've tried to use:

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([anotherNavController], animated: true)
```

However, I get a `NSException`. I'm assuming you cannot have a `UINavigationController` within another one because using `setViewControllers()` with a normal view controller works fine.

All I need is to dismiss the current navigationController and present another navigationController so that when the new navigationController is dismissed, in the future the old navigationController is not re-present.

I am using **[PageMenu](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu)** which complicates things.

Example of why I need to replace the whole navigation controller:

[image]

This code initializes the PageMenu in ViewDidAppear:

```
 // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

    pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Why are you replacing the _entire_ `navigationController`? Couldn't you just replace the `viewController` within?

Comment: Sadly, no. I am using https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu and it does not display correctly if it is not presented in its own navigation controller.

Comment: Judging by your posted image, it looks like you just need to add some padding to the top, not replace a `navigationController`.

Comment: How is your `AppDelegate` setup? Are your instantiating your custom navController, or are you instantiating the default?

Comment: I am using the standard Navigation Controller. How would I add padding?

Comment: Are you using StoryBoard to setup your PageMenu?

Comment: See my latest edit. The PageMenu is created within the view controller itself.

Comment: What is in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` Delegate method?

Comment: You can use an unwind segue to move to a particualar controller

Comment: @BhavukJain OP is looking to move to a different `NavigationController`, not `ViewController`.

Comment: func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        let theme = ThemeManager.currentTheme()
        ThemeManager.applyTheme(theme)
        
        return true
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're setting up your PageMenu without StoryBoard, you'll need to instantiate the `rootViewController` in your AppDelegate. This should get rid of the need to switch from the default `navigationController` to your own.

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    self.window?.rootViewController = YourViewController(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

For additional help setting up a PageMenu without StoryBoard, check out the demo code [here](https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu/tree/master/Demos/Demo%202/PageMenuDemoNoStoryboard/PageMenuDemoNoStoryboard).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am still using a story board for most of my controllers so that code in the application function would not apply to me. However, I still made the view controller that needed a navigation controller a XIB file. The tabs were still at the top so I moved them down:  

pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 63.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 80), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

I was able to use setViewControllers after all and still get the colored background.